# Transporting POST vars using SESSION

Tags: php, session, post

I'm using a page to transport POST vars to the next page and sometimes its completely empty. I haven't been able to reproduce it myself but see client's coming across this problem.

**Page1:**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['postvars'] = $_POST;
error_log("client was trying to save post: " . json_encode($_POST));
```

**Page2:**

```
session_start();
error_log(json_encode($_SESSION));
```

There's nothing fancy, everything is default `PHP` session ini, works when I test with `safari`, `ff`, `ie7+8`.  I even dump the client's `$_SERVER vars`, hoping their using `IE5` or something weird, no luck.  What the heck is going on?

Comment: you want to transport ALL POST VARS , right ?

Comment: Is there any significant time that passes between the two pages loading?

Comment: if cookies are disabled, and your using cookies to transmit the session id, then it will be blank, you can transmit the session id in the url, and\or check the user cookie status .

Comment: Have you checked if the session cookies are transmitted with each request and that the same cookie is being used? If the session ID changes each time, then something's killing your cookies and a new (blank) session is being created each time.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are setting enctype when you don't need to

Or check the content type of the post (force it on the receiving page if necessary)

Could also try this in your debugging to see what is being sent through

```
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 0):

AH sorry this was the problem.  In one of the comments for session_start()

For the problem of session lost after of redirect with header location...

Try with this:

header ("Location: xpage.php");
exit(); //This sentence do the magic
?>

So I was doing header redirects and SESSION was dropping.  I've confirmed this by getting the session_id() on both pages and having them be different sometimes.  I still can't reproduce this on any browser that I've tried on though.